# What do we say when we ask for an opinion to everyone in a group except the guy who just answered?

Tags: idiomatic-language

Let's say we asked a question to a group of people and a person already answered. What do we say to ask the others to answer? I thought about "What about the others", but this sounds unnatural to me, because it as if the person was talking in third person. "What about you guys" also seem to be wrong, because it's too imprecise since one person in the group already answered. What expression should be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several options. As long as we're talking about opinions, you could use:

> What does everyone else think?

If you don't want everyone to answer, just to see if anyone else has a different idea, you could try:

> Anyone have a different idea?
>   Does anyone disagree with [name]?
>   Any other thoughts?

The last one has to be clearly addressed to the wider group using tone and body language, of course.

Then there's the extremely succinct:

> Anyone else?